# how to iterating through json data in python?

Tags: json, python-2.7

I have a json output like below,

```
{
"took":3,"timed_out":false,"_shards":{"total":5,"successful":5,"failed":0},
"hits":{"total":2,"max_score":1.0,
"hits":
 [
 {
     "_index":"management",
     "_type":"",
     "_id":"/home/myfld1/myid1",
     "_score":1.0,  
     "_source" : 
     {
         "newslides": "User Mgmt1  ", 
         "metaData": 
         {
             "fileName": "file1", 
         }
     }
   },
   {
       "_index":"management",
       "_type":"",
       "_id":"/home/myfld3/myid3",
       "_score":1.0,
       "_source" : 
       {
           "newslides": "User mgmt2  ", 
           "metaData":
           {
               "fileName": "file2", 
           }
       }
   }
]
}
}
```

I am trying to get the "fileName" field from the above json. I have tried like this,

```
    for filenames in response["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"]["newslides"]["metaData"]:
        filearray.append(filenames["fileName"])
```

But i am getting one error like below,

```
for filenames in response["hits"]["hits"][0]["_source"]["newslides"]["metaData"]:
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

Please help me to get that file name.

Comment: You've got `["newslides"]` which should not be there. Otherwise, see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is simply a dictionary with some lists and other dictionaries in it. Just be careful and go through the elements iteratively:

```
filearray = []
for x in response["hits"]["hits"]:
    filearray.append(x["_source"]["metaData"]["fileName"])
```

or in one line:

```
filearray = [x["_source"]["metaData"]["fileName"] for x in response["hits"]["hits"]]
```